# NodeJS server send data to C++ process

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets, ipc

I have a nodeJS server which receives user POST/Streaming requests from a web-UI.

I have a C++ back-end engine process which does some calculations and sends API calls to other 3rd party services. The API call requires certain info provided by the web users.

My question is what is the best solution to pass the request data received on NodeJS and send over to the C++ process?

WebUI -> NodeJS ->???->> C++ engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your C++ application listen on a TCP or Unix socket. 
Make your NodeJs application connect to that socket and exchange messages. For messages you can use Google Protocol Buffers, JSON, etc..

Answer (score 0):

If the information what you have is still at JavaScript layer, then you have to implement C/C++ Addons implementation. If you already have some type of native module, then you may follow the same design based on that (very likely existing module could be based on NAN). If you are plan to introduce a brand new native module then it is a good time to consider N-API. You can get more information about it from.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/n-api.html

https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api